# How to split with the splitted value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

My data looks like this:

```
var data = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    925 940 TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT    3001    3016    15  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    2418    2433    TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT    3000    3015    15";
```

I want to split these data by the three consecutive numbers separated by space. 
So, I tried this:

```
var split_data = data.split(/\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+/);
```

I want to keep the split value joined with previous value. I want the following output:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    925 940 TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT    3001    3016    15
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    2418    2433    TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT    3000    3015    15
```

In Perl it can be easily achieved with the following pattern:

```
@split_data = split(/\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\K\s+/,$data);
```

Perl has support for `\K` operator, but JavaScript has not. How can I do it?

Comment: `(\s{3,})` will match 3 or more consecutive spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` here, but you need to use a reverse string trick to work around the missing look-behind feature in JavaScript.

```js
function revStr(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

var data = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    925 940 TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT    3001    3016    15  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    2418    2433    TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT    3000    3015    15";  
var split_data = revStr(data).split(/\s+(?=\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+)/i); 

var arrayLength = split_data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += revStr(split_data[i]) + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do a match instead of split.

```
(.*?\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s*)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/17

```
var re = /(.*?\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s*)/img; 
var str = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    925 940 TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT    3001    3016    15  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA    2418    2433    TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT    3000    3015    15';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
         re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```